# How to display Action colum when we convert VF Page into lightning page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have contact related list under the account. in Classic if I open any account the related contacts are showing with action column where we can check multiple contacts and mass update(Custom button).

[image]

But I converted this page into lightning by applying Lightningstylesheets= true. in lightning, The action column is not showing.

[image]

Do I need to write any component for this or can i do anything in VF Page itself?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there exists an Idea to [Allow Quick Action on related list](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2). So to speak as of now there doesnt exists a standard solution for it. You have to build a custom lightning component for it.